# jQuery Roundabout - Wrong postion of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, positioning

I'm using the [jQuery Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout) to create a simple JS Roundabout. I initalized the code with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.roundabout').roundabout({
    });
});
```

And gave the the elements the following CSS:

```
.roundabout-holder {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
}
.roundabout-moveable-item {
    height: 4em;
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.roundabout-in-focus {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

For some reason, the alignment of the elements is not correct on my test page. I have tried muliple things to fix the problem, but I can't figure out what is causing the problem. With the default settings I have on the site, the horizontal alignment should be on one line. Any idea what could be going wrong here?

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have set the API `tilt` to 0.

```
$('.roundabout').roundabout({
    tilt: 0
});
```

Also, if you are placing images inside your `.roundabout-moveable-item`, you need to make sure you set the width of the image to `100%`.

```
.roundabout-moveable-item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```